# Saving DialogFragment data only if button is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, android-dialogfragment

Hi!

I have a DialogFragment class that implements a TimePicker. The DialogFragment is binded with a PreferenceFragment class, which in turn is held by an Activity. Inside my Preferences, i have also 2 clickable Preferences, "Set" and "Exit". I want to save the values picked from TimePicker only if the "Set" button is pressed, if the "Exit" is pressed, i would like to not save the values from TimePicker and instead use the values that are set the last time "Set" was pressed. Bascially, i want the same behaviour like the default android alarm clock has.

How can this be done? I don't know how to "unsave" the values that i get inside DialogFragment from the PreferenceFragment class (this is the class i initialize the "Set" and "Exit" buttons)

I'm posting the code also, but you don't have to read through them to answer the question, i think.

PreferenceFragment class implementing clickable Preferences:

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        Preference setbutton = (Preference)getPreferenceManager().findPreference("set");      
        if(setbutton != null) 
        {
             setbutton.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                             return true;
                         }
                     });     
        }
        Preference exitbutton = (Preference)getPreferenceManager().findPreference("close");      
        if(exitbutton != null) 
        {
             exitbutton.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                             return true;
                         }
                     });     
        }
    }
```

DialogFragment implementing TimePicker dialog:

```
public class TimePreference extends DialogPreference {
    private int lastHour=0;
    private int lastMinute=0;
    private TimePicker picker=null;
    private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    public static int getHour(String time) {
        String[] pieces=time.split(":");

        return(Integer.parseInt(pieces[0]));
    }

    public static int getMinute(String time) {
        String[] pieces=time.split(":");

        return(Integer.parseInt(pieces[1]));
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt) {
        this(ctxt, null);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(ctxt, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(ctxt, attrs, defStyle);

        setPositiveButtonText("Set");
        setNegativeButtonText("Cancel");
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        picker=new TimePicker(getContext());

        return(picker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);

        picker.setCurrentHour(lastHour);
        picker.setCurrentMinute(lastMinute);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult) {
            lastHour=picker.getCurrentHour();
            lastMinute=picker.getCurrentMinute();

            String time=String.valueOf(lastHour)+":"+String.valueOf(lastMinute);

            if (callChangeListener(time)) {
                persistString(time);

            }
            setSummary(time);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return(a.getString(index));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
        String time=null;

        if (restoreValue) {
            if (defaultValue==null) {
                time=getPersistedString("00:00");
            }
            else {
                time=getPersistedString(defaultValue.toString());
            }
        }
        else {
            time=defaultValue.toString();
        }

        lastHour=getHour(time);
        lastMinute=getMinute(time);

        setSummary(time);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!